# What is the meaning of the decision tree algorithm name "c4.5"?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm learning Machine Learning. In this subject, I see a decision tree name "c4.5" but I do not know "c4.5" stand for what. Is there anyone help me? I search about it a lots but I still do not have the answer :D

Comment: Where do you see it? Any context?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen : Its another type of decision tree. In this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C4.5_algorithm), they told about it, but there is no one said  why that decision tree name "c4.5" :D

Comment: What that tells me is that it's an algorithm and not a decision tree. It does build one. And there's implementation info etc. So what actually is missing?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: I think I get some mistakes in here :D, decision tree could be built by "c4.5" algorithm or "ID3" algorithm, etc. I studied "ID3" algorithm in my class, and "ID3" = "Iterative Dichotomiser 3" - a specific name, I just wanna know the specific name of "c4.5" :D. It is not really a big matter :D

Comment: Oh lol, I always just assumed ID3 meant Identification Tree and never bothered to look into it :) !

Answer (score 4):

In the book "C4.5: Programs for Machine Learning" by Quinlan I wasn't able to quickly find an description of why that name was chosen (it's about 300 pages including appendices with lots of source code though, so didn't read all that).

The story I heard is that the "C" simply indicates that the algorithm was implemented in `C`, and that Quinlan was maybe very proud of the fact that he was able to program in `C`. Then I suppose the "4.5" is simply a version number of the software.

Note that a `Java` implementation of the same / a similar algorithm in `Weka` is named "J48".

Comment: its really an interesting answer :D, I love it very much :D

Comment: If this is true, I seriously doubt that Quinlan is insane. In ID3, the D is for 'Dichotomiser', it's very strange he don't pick 'binary', and what the '3' stands for is still unknown. What's the point, to make the algorithm sounds very fancy?

Comment: The newer and improved version is called C5.0 (See5 on Windows).